# Kafka: access to kafka server on vm from windows through public ip

Tags: apache-kafka, centos, remote-access

I hava a small problem. I want to connect to my kafka server on vm centos from windows Java producer script.

in **config/server.properties** I have a line:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<public ip>:9092
```

(for example: advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.239.83.27:9092)

and I still cannot produce messages from producer on windows. On Virtual Box I have set option "allow all" in network settings

Unable to run kafka server, while running constantly there is a **WARN**:
[controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Connection to node 0 **could not** be established. Broker may not be available (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient).

Please help :p

[image]

and my Java code on windows:

```
public class TwitterProducer {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TwitterProducer.class.getName());

String consumerKey = "xxx";
String consumerSecret = "xxx";
String token = "xxx";
String secret = "xxx";

public TwitterProducer() {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TwitterProducer().run();
}

public void run()
{
    logger.info("Setup");
    /** Set up your blocking queues: Be sure to size these properly based on expected TPS of your stream */
    BlockingQueue<String> msgQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(1000);

    // create a twitter client
    Client client = createTwitterClient(msgQueue);
    // Attempts to establish a connection.
    client.connect();

    // create a kafka producer
    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = createKafkaProducer();

    // on a different thread, or multiple different threads....
    while (!client.isDone()) {
        String msg = null;
        try {
            msg = msgQueue.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            client.stop();
        }
        if(msg != null){
            logger.info(msg);
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("twitter_tweets", null, msg), new Callback() {
                public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                    if (e != null){
                        logger.error("Something bad happened", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    logger.info("End of application");
}

public Client createTwitterClient(BlockingQueue<String> msgQueue)
{
    /** Declare the host you want to connect to, the endpoint, and authentication (basic auth or oauth) */
    Hosts hosebirdHosts = new HttpHosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST);
    StatusesFilterEndpoint hosebirdEndpoint = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();
    // Optional: set up some followings and track terms

    List<String> terms = Lists.newArrayList("bitcoin");
    hosebirdEndpoint.trackTerms(terms);


    // These secrets should be read from a config file
    Authentication hosebirdAuth = new OAuth1(consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, secret);

    ClientBuilder builder = new ClientBuilder()
            .name("Hosebird-Client-01")                              // optional: mainly for the logs
            .hosts(hosebirdHosts)
            .authentication(hosebirdAuth)
            .endpoint(hosebirdEndpoint)
            .processor(new StringDelimitedProcessor(msgQueue))
             ;                          // optional: use this if you want to process client events

    Client hosebirdClient = builder.build();
    return hosebirdClient;
}

public KafkaProducer<String, String> createKafkaProducer()
{

    String bootstrapServers = "193.239.83.27:9092";



    // create the producer properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

    // create the producer
    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
    return producer;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You say you have `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`

But the image shows that's commented out.

The logs also say Kafka is shutting down, so make sure the brokerId is a positive number and ensure Zookeeper is running

By the way, there's a Kafka Connect Twitter source that seems to do what you want

Comment: yes, I commented this line. Should it be uncommented??

Comment: you say to change Broker_id = 0 to Broker_id = positivie number for example 1?

Comment: Should I change host name from localhost to another in etc/hosts ??

Comment: omg, kafka is so sick.. I cannot cope with this. Simply I want to have remote elastic public ip access, nothing more

Comment: 1) properties aren't loaded if commented. The default doesn't listen externally 2) never use etc/hosts to solve this issue 3) I don't really know why your broker is stopping. And I assume you've read this https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/